# Regular Expression - Password

Tags: regex, pcre

What kind of string(password) does this regular expression match with `/^(\w*(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\w*[A-Z])\w*){6-20}$/` ?

I tried passwords with 6-20 characters which includes lower case[a-z], upper case[A-Z] and one numeral(0-9) but no joy!

Comment: Are you sure about the last part `{6-20}`? It does not mean "6 to 20 times", but match the literal string `{6-20}`. If you want to match "6 to 20 times", write `{6,20}` instead. But even with it, it has too many backtracks, some PCRE engines fail to find anything.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion works. You saved my day

Answer (score 0):

If this is Perl, the string must a digit, a lower-case letter, an upper-case letter plus any number of other `\w` characters and literally `{6-20}` at the end of the string.  For example, `1aA{6-20}` is true.

I think original author indented to have `{6,20}` instead of `{6-20}`.

It's a complicated regex.  I think the following would be easier to understand and quicker:

```
/^\w{6,20}$/ && /\d/ && /[a-z]/ && /[A-Z]/
```